# Cannot perform tag change on certain questions

Tags: bug, edits

Once in a while, I edit questions just to change or remove tags I find inappropriate. But in rare cases, this is not possible: Having removed a tag and written the "Edit summary", the red box appears, saying

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

though I did not modify the question's text at all. As mentioned above, in 99.9% cases, my tag-only edit gets submitted just fine. Example for a 0.1% question (I tried removing [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache)):

[How can use Apache Opennlp in a java project building in eclipse luna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578080)

Maybe the check for text modification fails on this particular one. I feel reluctant to editing the question's text as well only to circumvent that check...